# Create a Snake Tail in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a SnakeGame using pygame and I'm having some troubles with the Snake tail. The problem is that I literally have no IDEA how I should do this.

I check where is my snake going (up,down,left or right) and then I add +score blocks behind the snake head. In this way, if the Snake has eaten 4 apples, I'll add 4 blocks. But it is not the right way. I mean, the tail will be "straight" and will never turn if the snake head turns.

So my question is: how should I do that? 
I took some options, but they're a lot, for example:

1. checking all the time the body coordinates, but I think it would
   become hard to do
2. creating a list and add the snake head position when it turns, but then what should I do?
3. using all my snake body blocks like a head, so it would be like adding a block behind the snake head
4. always add a block behind the head and delete the last one, but I don't know how to create the code to do this

Comment: Sorry, but this is far too broad. SO is about specific programming issues, we can't debate a giant block of code and your next steps forward, the format just won't allow it.

Comment: Ok, let me edit the question. What I'm looking for is not someone who gives me an already done program. It would be silly! I was just asking if someone who had already done something like that is able to explain me how he did it. Maybe I made the question too big or hard to read.

Comment: I create list with positions of all elements - head and all elements in tail. When snake move then I add head position at the beginning so old head automatically become first element in tail. old first automatically become second element, etc. And then I remove last element on list to keep snake length. And when snake eats apple then I don't delete last element and it makes snake longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array of snake blocks (here I called it `snake`). For example, the first element will be snake's head, and the last will be its tail.

When the snake is moving (pseudocode):

```
snake.insert(0, snake[0] + cur_direction)  # move snake's head
snake.pop()  # delete its old tail, so that the snake doesn't become longer
```

And when you eat an apple, you just don't have to delete the tail (because now the snake is one block longer)